# Animating a polygon drawn with vertices

Tags: animation, xna, polygon, primitive

First off: I had another question [Creating a 2D polygon in XNA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246459/creating-a-2d-polygon-in-xna) but I answered it myself after a day of frustrating research and testing. There you can find the code I have right now. So here is my next question, as I can't find anything about it. How do I animate a `VertexPositionColor[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To animate a VertexPositionColor[], all you really need to do is modify the elements of the array appropriately and then use the new values in your DrawUserPrimitives() call.

For example, in the Update method of your game:

```
for ( int index = 0; index < vertices.Length; ++index )
{
    vertices[ index ].Color *= (float)System.Math.Sin( gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds / 60 );
}
```